# Objective-C Set Property from Another Class Returns Null

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to init properties `firstName` and `lastName` in `XYZPerson` from my `int main()` in different ways. (I'm learning OC and exploring different ways of initializing values)

However, `NSLog` always returns `null` for `firstName`. I know there are many questions similar to mine, but almost all of them are leaning towards a specific issue but not language grammar itself.

````
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "XYZShoutingPerson.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        XYZPerson *somePerson = [[XYZPerson alloc] init];
        
        NSString *firstName = [somePerson firstName];
        [somePerson setFirstName:@"Jonny"];
        [somePerson setLastName:@"Appleseed"];

        NSLog(@"%@ %@", firstName, [somePerson lastName]); // prints ```(null) Appleseed```
    }
    return 0;
}
````

```
@interface XYZPerson : NSObject

@property NSString *firstName;
@property NSString *lastName;

- (id)init;
- (id)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)aFirstName lastName:(NSString *)aLastName;
- (void)saySomething:(NSString *)greeting;

@end
```

I am just starting to learn Objective-C. I know this is most likely to be a very silly mistake, so pls don't be too harsh on me... Thanks!

Comment: You access the `firstName` property and store it in a local variable before setting that property. So the `firstName` local variable is `null`.

Comment: Yeah, that worked! But I wonder why storing it as local property before setting it doesn't work? Doesn't the address ```firstName``` points to remains the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yeah, that worked! But I wonder why storing it as local property before setting it doesn't work? Doesn't the address `firstName` points to remains the same?

It does, which is why your code doesn't work...

The following rounds a few edges but hopefully gets the concepts across.

Let's take a step back from properties and just look at *variables*, the properties you have are just variables with a little code around them which has no impact here on what's going on.

A variable is just a named *box*, and that box is capable of storing a (computer) representation, aka *value*, of something with a particular *type*. E.g the declaration:

```
int height;
```

Is an instruction to use an available[1] box that is capable of holding a representation of something with type `int` and to name that box `height`.

When you assign to a variable what happens is whatever is already in the box is thrown away[2] and then a *copy* of the value being assigned is placed in the box.

When you read from a variable a *copy* of what is in the box is made and returned to you.

Now it doesn't matter what the type of value is stored in the box, the above description of the process remains true.

In your case what is stored in your boxes are values of type `NSString *`, that is a *reference* or *pointer* to something which represents (in whatever way the computer does so) a string, essentially that reference *is* the representation of the string.

Now consider the assignment:

```
height = 42;
```

This always assigns the representation of `42` into the variable/box named `height` – an *integer literal* always represents the same value [3].

The same is true for a *string literal*, so the literal `@"Jonny"` *always* represents the string "Jonny".

Now let's look at your code and describe what it is doing in terms of (the underlying) variables (the properties are just wrappers for):

```
NSString *firstName = [somePerson firstName];
```

Copy the current value in `somePerson`'s `firstName` variable into the local variable `firstName`. From what you report at this point in your code `somePerson`'s `firstName` contains the representation of `null` so that is what is copied.

```
[somePerson setFirstName:@"Jonny"];
```

Copy the representation of `@"Jonny"` into `somePerson`'s `firstName` variable throwing away whatever is already there – in your case a representation of `null`

```
[somePerson setLastName:@"Appleseed"];
```

Copy the representation of `@"Appleseed"` into `somePerson`'s `lastName` variable

```
NSLog(@"%@ %@", firstName, [somePerson lastName]);
```

Copy the representations in the local variable `firstName` – a representation of `null` – and in `somePerson`'s `lastName` – a representation of `@"Appleseed"` – and pass them to `NSLog` to convert into printable text and output.

Your misunderstanding might stem from hearing about the type `NSMutableString`. One of these is represented by a box whose contents can be *modified* (aka "mutated") rather than simply *replaced*. The representation of an `NSMutableString` is a reference/pointer to its box, just as an `NSString`, but in its case what is in the box can be modified while the reference/pointer will stay the same as the name of the box itself doesn't change.

Hope that helped more than it confused! (It is easier to explain using pictures/a whiteboard.)

---

[1] How the computer finds an available box is interesting but not important here.

[2] "thrown away" can be quite involved and you'll discover mare as you learn, there is something called "garbage collection" which you'll find out about under the term "ARC" in Objective-C. But again that is not important to your question...

[3] Those old/learned enough to know about the early days of FORTRAN who wish to pipe up and say "Ah, but..." at this point go stand in the corner ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! If I'm not mistaken, ```firstName``` is merely a pointer that points to the value copied: ```null```, rather than the value it copied from: ```[somePerson firstName]```. Therefore, the value of ```firstName``` remains the same despite changes are made to its data source.

Comment: Not quite, `firstName` contains a copy of the reference that was in `somePerson`'s `firstName` - the string value itself is not copied only a reference to it. When the property is then set a different reference is copied into it, and this copy doesn't impact the contents of `firstName`. HTH